# Multi-Level (Sparse) A/B Testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, multilevel-analysis, ab-test

I've been reading some articles about Bayesian A/B testing such as:

http://engineering.richrelevance.com/bayesian-ab-tests/

but my application requires a framework for handling sparsity and group level effects.  If the goal were regression, I would have no problem dealing with these issues, but inference is less in my wheel-house.

I was wondering if anyone has come across a similarly well laid out framework for this application.  I don't believe this question is repeated, but if it is, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

The more I think about this, the more the word logistic keeps coming to mind.  Would the following be reasonable:

Let $t \in \{A, B\}$ be a treatment, and $g \in \{ 1,\dots, n\}$ be a group.  I have data of the form $(T_{t,g}, S_{t,g})$, trials and successes.  Assume the following priors:
$$
\alpha \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2), \\
\beta_g \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \tau^2).
$$
I could now model,
$$
S_{t,g} \sim \mathcal{B}(T_{t,g}, p_{t,g}), \\ 
p_{t,g} = logit^{-1}(\alpha\cdot\delta_{t,B} + \beta_g).
$$

So, for a fixed $(\mu, \sigma, \tau)$, I should be able to work out (though it might be ugly, oh how I miss you conjugacy) the posterior distribution of $\alpha$.  Then I could proceed with the same Monte Carlo approach used in the article.

My hesitation is that this doesn't feel natural.  Where did Beta go.  Did I have to desert it?  The idea of choosing which Beta prior to use, seems like a much more comfortable position than choosing $\sigma, \tau$.